# Getting error when trying to use Redux Toolkit with MUI ToggleButtonGroup component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, redux-toolkit

The error message begins as:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

The `handleChange` function ran without error until I tried to update Redux state with a dispatcher.

This worked fine:

```js
const [alignment, setAlignment] = React.useState('12');

const handleChange = (event, newAlignment) => {
  setAlignment(newAlignment);
};
```

But I want to elevate the state to Redux-Toolkit. Changing the function as below caused the error:

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch;

const handleChange = (event, newAlignment) => {
  dispatch(setNbTasks(newAlignment));
};
```

I tried a couple of things, but got nowhere, the details are above.

Comment: No issue, I was meaning to click your response so it had the green tick showing on the left-hand side.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks for responding back so quickly. Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving the `useDispatch` hook to variable named `dispatch` and then calling the hook function from the callback function which breaks the [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

> ### Only Call Hooks at the Top Level
>
> **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.** Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function,
> before any early returns. By following this rule, you ensure that
> Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.
> That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks
> between multiple `useState` and `useEffect` calls.

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch; // dispatch === useDispatch -> true

const handleChange = (event, newAlignment) => {
  dispatch(setNbTasks(newAlignment)); // -> useDispatch(....); 
};
```

The `useDispatch` hook should be invoked first, and the *returned* dispatch function saved to local variable `dispatch`.

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch(); // Invoke hook, get dispatch function

const handleChange = (event, newAlignment) => {
  dispatch(setNbTasks(newAlignment)); // Ok dispatch call now 
};
```